# T-test for mean difference in one variable for data with lots of (potentially correlated) variables

Tags: correlation, t-test, inference, sample

I have a really basic question. I don't know how to formulate it correctly, so I did not find any helpful resources yet. Pointers to anything would be highly appreciated.

So the issue is that I'd like to compare the mean of prices of two groups of homes. Ones with garden and ones without. Within my data I do have information regarding the size of the interior home, the total area... Many variables. Some of them are definitely related to having a garden or not.

What I'm doing up to know is simply comparing the means and constructing a two sample t-test for homes with and without garden. This feels kind of wrong as I'm not accounting for all the other variables.

So my question is: Should I, in some way account for the other variables, while comparing the means of price for the two groups?
And if so, how can I do this.

Thanks for any help on this basic question:)

Comment: That depends on what your question is. Is your goal to estimate the mean price of these two groups? Is your goal to determine whether the price is different, after accounting for all the additional stuff that the houses may have?

Comment: It's the latter one. Determine whether the difference in the prices is "significant" while accounting for all the other stuff;)

Comment: The trouble with this is that a garden sounds like a nice luxury to have in a house. Perhaps that is correlated with other luxuries. If houses with gardens also tend to have pools, how can you attribute to gardens that the price is higher?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to quantify how much, if any, effect some variables have on the price of a house, a natural choice would be a linear model, assuming your data is appropriate. A coefficient for each variable in the data would be estimated, which would show how much the price of a house would increase if this variable were included (or a slope for a continuous variable). Each coefficient would also have a standard error, from which you can obtain a confidence interval and the dreaded p-value (from which you could infer something about "significant" effects).